# I can't resolve error with API POST function

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script

I am trying to post data via an API interface.

I have checked the JSON of the data with JSON formatter and tested the API post in ReqBin and they work fine but when I execute it in App Script I get the same error, seemingly ignoring the attributes I put in the options variable.

Error is
{"code":"not_acceptable","message":"I can only talk JSON. Please set 'Accept' and 'Content-Type' to 'application/json' in your http request header."}

Note: I have tried sending just the data as the payload without json.stringify'ing it as it is formatted as JSON to start with.

In all cases it executes, but comes back 406

Is there another way to add 'Accept':"application/json" into the header??

**My Code**

```
    function exportNation()
   {
   // Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
   var data = {  
   "person":
   {  
          "email":"mikenizzckelisaweiner@tv.com",
          "last_name":"Bozzrovowski",
          "first_name":"Edwzzard",
          "tags":"Imported Data,Volunteer,Sign Request"
      }
    };
 
    var options = {
      "method":"POST",
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
      'Accept':"application/json",
      'muteHttpExceptions':true,
      'payload':JSON.stringify(data)
    };
  
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://xyz.xyz.com/api/v1/people? 
    access_token=5604da84fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX42da1ea',options );

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Additional HTTP headers need to be sent as a headers object.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters

```
var options = {
  "method":"POST",
  "contentType":"application/json",
  "headers": {'Accept':"application/json"},
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.  I have changed my options definition but I am still getting the same error.  It seems to be ignoring the Accept portion.

    var options = {
      "method":"POST",
      'muteHttpExceptions':true,
      "headers": {'Accept':"application/json"},
      "headers": {'Content-Type':"application/json"},
      'payload':JSON.stringify(data)
    };

Comment: Okay, I tried the same with the content type outside the headers tag and it worked!  Thanks so much!!